# Is StackExchange legally obliged to periodically release data dumps of all sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-dump, legal

The question is sparked from this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267356/184300) and the discussion below it.

Is there anything that obliges StackExchange to periodically release data dumps (and keep the already released data dumps accessible), or could the executive team in principle decide to stop releasing new and remove the already published data dumps?

Comment: Really what needs to happen is a concerned group of users should use one of the many clone Q&A systems out there, setup with the datadump content and claim victory as the clone is swamped with ads for Oakleys and Maximum Gain Strength

Comment: Are you asking whether you and Frank have understood the legalities of CC-BY-SA 3.0? It seems like http://opensource.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate. I think you've understood it fine, to which the answer to this question is "no".

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards yes, I want to understand the legal situation ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. They are not required to. The questions and answers are released under the CC license. That doesn't mean they can't stop all servers at any time they want to. You don't pay them to keep a service alive.

If you want to, you can store and redistribute the data dump at will. Put it in an own site with the same license and attribution to its author and you will be fine.

Comment: (Attribution to the author(s), but [most likely not to Stack Exchange](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/429/31)).

Comment: That is the definition of the license indeed. The attribution is to users, not the company. Although you are required to link to the authors' SE profile as on the legal page.

Comment: @fra clarified the attribution part